# Java - How to decrypt using algorithm "AES/CBC/NOPADDING"?

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am trying to have 2 clients communicate securely with one another using the CBC algorithm of the Advanced Encryption Standard in Java. To implement this, I pad a plaintext String to be a multiple of 16 bytes, then encrypt it with a random 16 byte Initialization Vector and a set, shared, 32 byte key. The resulting cipher will be encoded in Base64 and appended by a ":" followed by the IV, also encoded in Base64.

Here is the implementation in Java:

```
public static String encrypt(String plainText, String keyString) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    // add padding to the plain text
    while (plainText.length() % 16 != 0) {
        plainText += " ";
    }

    // keyString is utf-8 encoded
    // use a 16 byte randomly populated iv
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
    // create a new cipher with the specified key and iv
    Cipher cipher = getCipher(keyString, iv);
    // encrypt the plain text
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
    // return the (cipher:iv), individually base64 encoded
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText) + ":" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(iv);
}
```

The method getCipher() is shared between the encryption and decryption method:

```
private static Cipher getCipher(String keyString, byte[] iv) {
    // keyString is utf-8 encoded
    // use a 16 byte randomly populated iv
    // create a new cipher with the specified key and iv
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NOPADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cipher;
}
```

An example of this is the key being "12345678901234567890123456789012", plainText "Hello World", resulting in: "tEGeM6ls3Z2J1ov8qb5Anw==:Mn3UKr4CwrBLJmT9tih9Pw==".

This now needs to be decrypted using the exact reverse of the encrypt method, which I have come up with as follows:

```
public static String decrypt(String cipherText, String keyString) throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    // split the cipher text and iv
    String[] cipherTextAndIv = cipherText.split(":");
    // decode the cipher text and iv
    byte[] cipherTextBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherTextAndIv[0]);
    byte[] iv = Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherTextAndIv[1]);
    // create a new cipher with the specified key and iv
    Cipher cipher = getCipher(keyString, iv);
    // decrypt the cipher text
    byte[] plainTextBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherTextBytes);
    // return the plain text
    return new String(plainTextBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}
```

However, this only returns the same, constant garbage:

- "???2?(?????.(" as resulting String or
- [-71, -70, -22, -127, 50, -33, -65, 40, -100, -98, -26, -28, 21, -3, 46, 40] as the byte array

May someone please help me in telling me where the issue is with my decryption method?

Comment: `getCipher()` calls `init()` with `Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE`. While this is correct for encryption, it is of course wrong for decryption, here `Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE` must be applied.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved the problem. Would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: A key is never a String. There are only two methods in your `getCipher` and now it requires three arguments. At that point in time it would be easier to remove the method.